# JQuery function onKeyUp focus next / previous

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a mobile verify function. Four input values with same class.

```js
    function isNumberKeyNext(evt){
    
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
        if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
                if ((charCode == 8 || charCode == 46)) {
                    $(this).prev('input').focus();
                } else {
                    $(this).next().focus();
                }
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" class="mobile-verify pass" maxlength="1" name="code[]"  onkeypress="return isNumberKeyNext(event)" />
    <input type="number" class="mobile-verify pass" maxlength="1" name="code[]"  onkeypress="return isNumberKeyNext(event)" />
    <input type="number" class="mobile-verify pass" maxlength="1" name="code[]"  onkeypress="return isNumberKeyNext(event)" />
    <input type="number" class="mobile-verify pass" maxlength="1" name="code[]"  onkeypress="return isNumberKeyNext(event)" />
```

HTML.

I just want to input NUMBERS, And if it is a proper number, focus next field, and if backspace is pressed, it should focus previous field. How can I achieve that? Where have I made an error? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/0qhgjc4g/#&togetherjs=LNy2oLSCab)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<input type="number" id="1" class="mobile-verify pass" maxlength="1" name="code[]"  onkeyup="return isNumberKeyNext(event,this)" maxlength="1"/>
    <input type="number" id="2" class="mobile-verify pass" maxlength="1" name="code[]"  onkeyup="return isNumberKeyNext(event,this)" maxlength="1" />
    <input type="number" id="3" class="mobile-verify pass" maxlength="1" name="code[]"  onkeyup="return isNumberKeyNext(event,this)" maxlength="1"/>
    <input type="number" id="4" class="mobile-verify pass" maxlength="1" name="code[]"  onkeyup="return isNumberKeyNext(event,this)" maxlength="1"/>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
function isNumberKeyNext(evt,$this){

        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
        if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        {
            $($this).val('');
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
                if ((charCode == 8 || charCode == 46)) {
                    $($this).prev('input').focus();
                } else {
                    $($this).next('input').focus();
                }
        }
    }
```